# What's the convention on placing curly braces in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have seen different conventions for Objective-C ([Cocoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29)/[Cocoa Touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_Touch)) of placing the curly braces.

The two that I have seen are:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
```

vs.

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}
```

This confuses me because I would expect that for such a rather small community there should be only one convention.

Which one of the two is more common?

Comment: I came looking for this answer because this is the best site for learning objective-c and I want to follow the apple convention but see some discrepancy. But even as I searched, I just _knew_ that not only would I find the answer here but that it would be closed. Technically it doesnt fit the criteria, sure - but this is just heavy handed. Now I have to find the answer in some other site

Comment: "rather small community" ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's any canonical answer to this (whether speaking in terms of objective-c or any other language).  Personally I prefer:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [super dealloc];
}
```

...but there are certainly a lot of people who prefer the alternate style, as well.  As for which is more common, [example code provided by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20) appears to prefer the first style (brace on the same line), so that would be a safe bet as the more common pattern.  I do recall stumbling across an older Apple coding conventions document which recommended the second style (brace on the next line), however (but it also recommended using two spaces instead of 4 for indents, which makes that document garbage in my opinion).  You might as well just pick your preference.

The only thing that I would recommend is that you should never mix both styles in a single source file.  Pick one and stick with it.  And if you're editing a third-party source file that uses one convention, follow that same convention instead of using the alternate format.  Then at least your coding style will always be consistent per compilation-unit.

Comment: the linked document does not prefer one style, it mixes both.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure style question and there is only one convention : choose the one you prefer.